# How do you eat a Delphi VCL TPageControl Key to stop it from beeping?

Tags: delphi

I have a `TPageControl` with several pages.  The form has an `OnKeyDown` event handler that detects if <kbd>Alt-N</kbd> is pressed and switches the `ActivePage` to the correct page.  That works, but I get a beep.

I tried eating the key in the Form's `OnKeyDown` event by setting `Key:=0`, but that didn't work.

I setup an `OnKeyPress` handler for the Form, but that is not called.

I presume it generates a `WM_CHAR` message that needs to be eaten, but I don't know where to intercept that in Delphi.

I see some special `CM_` messages that Delphi has, but I couldn't find any details on them.  I'm not sure if those would help.  I saw one thread somewhere that said I could do it with the `WinSvc` unit, but that was the extent of it.

Could someone explain how to prevent the beep?

Comment: Good reading: [A Key’s Odyssey](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528152626/https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447). It explains how key messages pass through the VCL, and the different ways you can hook/handle them at various levels of the framework.

Comment: "_Preventing the beep_" is not necessary when it's not played in general (that setting can be turned off in Windows). Also: [in Windows 10/11 the dialog box shortcuts **Ctrl + _number_** already "_moves to the nth tab_"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec#WindowsVersion=Windows_10).

Comment: @AmigoJack: Ctrl+number doesn't move to a particular tab in a VCL `TPageControl`. Also, I think I understand what the OP wants to achieve here. The beep, or "invalid operation notification" as I tend to think of it as, means that the keyboard command was invalid and does nothing. For instance, if you open the Run dialog (Win+R) and press Ctrl+Q, you get a beep. That's Windows telling you, "I don't understand that command so I did nothing". If the OP now makes Alt+n actually do something, it definitely makes sense to suppress the beep.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments it turns out using `TApplicationEvents` works.

```
procedure TMyForm.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
  var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if Msg.message=WM_SYSCHAR then
   if Windows.GetForegroundWindow()=Handle then
      if (Msg.WParam>=Ord('0')) and (Msg.WParam<=Ord('9'))  then
         Handled:=True;
end;
```

Comment: It would be better to handle the `WM_SYSCHAR` message in the Form itself. Override the Form's `WndProc()` method, or use a `message` handler method. Either way, you don't need the `GetForegroundWindow()` check, as the message wouldn't have been delivered to your Form's window if it wasn't the foreground window to begin with

Comment: I tried the message handler and it didn't stop the beep from what I recall.

Comment: Were you passing the message to the inherited handler? If so, don't, eg: `procedure WMSysChar(var Msg: TWMChar); message WM_SYSCHAR; ... procedure TMyForm.WMSysChar(var Msg: TWMChar); begin if (Msg.CharCode < Ord('0')) or (Msg.CharCode > Ord('9')) then inherited; end;`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I remember now that I tried it again - it works if the sheets don't have focus - if you click on one of the sheet controls then try it, it beeps again.  The Application method doesn't beep even that way.

Comment: Probably because `WM_SYSCHAR` is posted to the window with keyboard focus. So, if a TabSheet is focused, the Form won't get the message, and vice versa.  I guess in that case, using the `OnMessage` event makes sense.